# Dynamically loading jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am planning to use Jquery DataTable to display user inbox. I want to load the user messages partially when he clicks on the page number or next or prev button.

from my initial research i think that jquery DataTable needs all table data before it is rendered.

Does any one knows whether there is any possible way to load data tables on user request ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can easily add data to DataTable, just take a look at documentation :

http://datatables.net/api#fnAddData

Or http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Comment: thanks, but is it possible to send custom data to the ajax source ?

Comment: Ok, I found how to send custom variables for ajaxsource 
http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html

Answer (score 1):

You can re-initialize data on Datatable dynamically like.

```
// clear all Datatable instance object 
$('#sample').DataTable().clear();

// re-initialize array values using foreach
sample_array = ['car','apple']
$.each(sample_array, function( index, value ) {
      $('#sample').dataTable().fnAddData( [value]);
});
```